# Использование пакетов в IronPython

Tags: c#, ironpython

Есть ли возможность использовать в IronPython (как дополнение в C#) дополнительные пакеты? В частности,  я работаю с opencv. Если возможно, то как?

UPD. Ошибка "unexpected token 'from'" возникает здесь:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
from pathlib import Path
from pytesseract import *
```

Comment: Сказывается глубокая ночь...) Импортировал opencv. Но теперь IronPython ругается на "from" (unexpected token 'from') в "from pytesseract import *". Что для этого нужно импортировать - хороший вопрос

Comment: Нужно смотреть что у вас выше from идет. Возможно там какая-то проблема с синтаксисом.

Comment: Код прекрасно работает в PyCharm - иначе бы и не пробовал использовать его дальше))

Comment: Прекрасно, что у вас прекрасно работает PyCharm. Но ничего конкретно нельзя сказать по вашему вопросу, потому что слишком много неизвестных: например, как конкретно выглядит ваш код, как вы его запускаете "как дополнение в C#" и т.д.

Comment: Как догадка - возможно в PyCharm вы запускаете интерпретатором Python3, а IronPython поддерживает только синтаксис Python2. Но это только догадка.

Comment: Собственное, здесь и загвоздка) Что из этого неверно?))
```import cv2
import numpy as np
from pathlib import Path
from pytesseract import *```

Comment: Добавьте информацию в сам вопрос. Откуда мне знать, может у вас в коде именно так как вы написали в комментарии - все в одну строку? Тогда логично было бы, если бы написало `unexpected token 'from'`

Comment: Собственно, часть кода добавлена

Comment: Всё еще актуально